# Is there a way to do a redirect using web workers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, web-worker

I'm trying to solve a problem with web pages on mobile devices on inactive browser tabs. Almost all mobile devices freeze JavaScript if the browser is not in focus and I'm trying to do a location change/redirect after 10s of inactivity.

While you can easily do this using setTimeout and location on a desktop browser, the setTimeout is of course frozen on mobile. I thought about using Date, but again if you spend more than 10s away from the browser, it will at best redirect you once the browser is in focus again.

So this doesn't fix the issue, as it can take much more than 10s for to user to return to the browser and trigger the redirect.

Web workers get around the freeze (tested) since they work in the background even if the browser page isn't in focus. But while they can count down the 10s accurately, I'm not sure if there's a way for them to change the location at that point.

I know they have no access to DOM, so does that mean there's also no way to change the page location (via history API or similar)?

I'm also open to alternative solutions to this (doesn't need to use web workers).

Comment: does the webWorker callback function work on inactive pages ? Then your problem is solved.

Comment: It works as expected on iOS. On Windows Phone it does not. And I'm yet to test it on some new Android since the one I have handy doesn't even support web workers.

Comment: Web workers not only don't have access to the DOM, but also the `window` global scope object, so they can't affect the URL via `window.location.href`. You've probably already seen this, but here's a list of everything available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers As @Cracker0dks points out, unless your `worker.onmessage` callback executes in the background, I'm not sure how you'll accomplish this with Web Workers.